# Kafka Consumer stuck at deserialization

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I created a simple producer-consumer app that using a custom Serializer and Deserializer.

After adding a new method to the Message class that I produce, the consumer started being stack at deserialization. My producer is using the new class (with the new method) and the consumer is using the old class (without the method).

I didn't add any new data members to the message that is sent!

I have multiple class messages that all are based on the following base class:

```
public enum MessageType{
    A,
    B,
    C,
}

public class Message implements Serializable {

    protected long id;
    protected MessageType type;

    public Message(int id , MessageType type) {
        this.id=id;
        this.type=type;
    }
```

Each one of the messages classes add some data members that are relevant to that message type.

For example:

```
public class MessageA extends Message{
    private String name;

    public MessageA(int id, String name) {
        super(id,MessageType.A);
        this.name = name;
    }
```

My Serializer:

```
public class MessageSerializer implements Serializer<Message> {
    @Override
    public byte[] serialize(String topic, Message msg) {
        return SerializationUtils.serialize(msg);    
}

    @Override
    public void configure(Map<String, ?> configs, boolean isKey) {}

    @Override
    public void close() {}
}
```

My Deserializer :

```
public class MessageDeserializer implements Deserializer<Message> {

    @Override
    public void configure(Map<String, ?> configs, boolean isKey) {}

    @Override
    public Message deserialize(String topic, byte[] data) {
        if(data == null)
            return null;
        log.info("Deserializing msg");
        Message msg= (Message) SerializationUtils.deserialize(data);
        if(msg== null){
            log.warn("Deserialization failed, got null as a result.");
            return null;
        }
        log.info("Deserialization complete");
        return msg;
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {}
    
    }
```

I added a new method to MessageC class which is a subclass of Message. The new class version is available only on the producer and not on the consumer. Although I didn't change the schema of the class, can that change cause a problem in the deserialization in the consumer?

After producing a MessageC message, my consumer printed `"Deserializing msg"` but it is stuck/failed since it didn't print any exception or `"Deserialization complete"`.

Can JSONSerializer/Deserializer handles those type of fixes? If I'll use JSONSerialzier it should care only regarding the schema of the class, right?

Comment: Do you have a copy of the stacktrace? and logs?

Comment: no stacktrace since no exception. The only msg I see is : Deserializing msg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use  `JsonSerializer` it should not be affected by changes to the methods - only changes to the data fields. Other serializers can serialize the whole object including the methods.

Comment: So If you use a custom serializer and you add a new method to the class you produce, you need to deploy the new class to both the producer and the consumer ? Correct me If I got it wrong, but JsonSerializer fixes this problem since it is based only on schema and not on class structure that includes methods ?

Comment: In general for java, it's simpler to have the same class in both consumer and producer. However, in some cases maybe you want a smaller version on the consumer side. If you are using a json library (e.g. jackson or json serializer/deserializer) it will only focus on your java data fields and getter/setter methods. It should ignore all other types of methods that are not getters or setters. If your using another serializer like e.g. default java, it also looks at stuff like version of the class.

Comment: I see. In my case, I have one producer and multiple consumers. The message object is shared between them. I can update the message class and the producer code very often but I cant upgrade the consumers code that often. So If I add a method in the Message class I want it to have less effect on the consumers. I guess in this case, the JSON Serialzier will be a good fit instead of my current serializer.

Comment: Yes, the json serializer/deserialize will only be affected by changes to get*(), set*(), and data fields. But not the rest of the class. 

Give it a try!

Comment: Thank you very much ! I will try it tomorrow and mark the solution if it will work :)

Comment: Since I'm not using spring kafka I dont have out of the box the JsonSerializer. Instead, I can use object mapper to map the object to bytes like done in the following post - https://medium.com/@asce4s/send-and-receive-json-objects-with-kafka-java-client-41bfbb4de108    . Does the object mapper mapps also only the fields ?

Comment: Yes, the objectmapper works with the fields..and the getters setters. Any other methods are ignored.

Answer (score 0):

As @Menelaos suggested, the solution was to use JsonSerializer. You can find an implementation in [here](https://medium.com/@asce4s/send-and-receive-json-objects-with-kafka-java-client-41bfbb4de108) .